# Splitting polynomial with negatives

Tags: java, polynomials, exponent

I am writing a program to add and subtract user inputted polynomials but I ran into trouble dealing with negative numbers. The program will work fine with positive numbers but I get the following output with negative numbers.

Output:

```
Coeficent: -2x^-2+3
Coeficent: 6
Exponent: 0
Exponent: 0
Exponent: 0
Exponent: 1
Exponent: 0
```

Code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
String polynomial= "-2x^-2+3x^1+6";
String[] parts = polynomial.split("x\\^\\d+\\+?");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println("Coeficent: " + part);
}
String[] terms = polynomial.split("(-|\\+)");
for (String term : terms) {
    String[] exponent = term.split("\\^");
    System.out.println("Exponent: " + (exponent.length > 1 ? exponent[1] : "0"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that separates out the two parts of each term:

```
public static void main(String ...args) {

    Pattern termPat = Pattern.compile("([+-]?(\\d+|(?=x)))(x(\\^([+-]?(\\d+)))?)?");

    System.out.println("Input: " + polynomial);

    int pos = 0;
    Matcher m = termPat.matcher(polynomial);
    while (true) {
        if (!m.find(pos))
            break;
        int coeff = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1) + (m.group(2).length() == 0 ? "1" : ""));
        int degree = Integer.parseInt((m.group(3) == null)? "0" : (m.group(5) == null)? "1" : m.group(5));
        System.out.println(String.format("Term - Coeff: %d  Degree: %d", coeff, degree));
        pos = m.end();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Input: -2x^-2+3x^1+6
Term - Coeff: -2  Degree: -2
Term - Coeff: 3  Degree: 1
Term - Coeff: 6  Degree: 0
```

Comment: Enhanced my answer so you can leave off the '^1', and parsed each part of each term to a number.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. I went adapted this to store it in a 2D array and eventually a Linked List.

Comment: Updated my answer again.  Now this thing should take any valid polynomial form.  You can leave the coefficient off the 'x' now.  -  Please click the check mark if this was indeed what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider sequence of mathematical operations. Split step-by-step:

- first, split additions/subtractions, but here check if your finding has a left-operand. If there is no left-operand, it's a sign instead of an operation.
  So, identify those +/- which do have a number or a variable on its left side, but NO operatator.
- Then, split multiplications and divisions
- Finally, split for those operations with highest priority - in your case, exponential function

Answer (score 0):

You could expand on using a regular expression for splitting input.

Using the regex: `((?:[\-\+]\dx\^[\-\+]\d)|[\-\+]\d)` will give you a **proper start** to capture polynomials with all +/- signs written out. For example: `+2x^+2+3x^+1+4x^-3+6` would be an accepted input. You would then interate through the matches and process each for themself. The example before will give you the following matches:

1. `+2x^+2`
2. `+3x^+1`
3. `+4x^-3`
4. `+6`

try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/OuQKd6/1)